# Contar número de registros em uma base de dados

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Quero contar o número de registros de uma tabela da base de dados. Tenho 3 registos na minha DB, mas o resultado é sempre 1. Utilizei este código:

```
$base_hndl = new SQLite3("p.sqlite");
$select = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
$resultat = $base_hndl->exec($select);                      
echo "Utilizadores conectados ".$resultat;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você olhar a [documentação](https://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php) verá que o retorno do método `exec` é do tipo booleano, ou seja, ele vai retornar 0 (`false`) se a operação falhou ou 1 (`true`) se a operação foi bem sucedida. Por isto você sempre recebe 1, a operação sempre está ocorrendo sem problemas.

O `exec` é para executar não *queries*, ou seja, para executar comandos que não dão resultados a não ser pela informação se ele ocorreu sem problemas. Casos típicos são o `CREATE`, O `INSERT`, etc.

Quando você está buscando informações no banco de dados, ou seja, está usando `SELECT` precisa usar métodos que tragam esses resultados para uma variável ou possam ser lidos com outros métodos da classe.

Para obter o resultado que deseja provavelmente você precisará do método [`QuerySingle()`](https://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.querysingle.php) ou eventualmente o [Query](https://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php). Não deve ser o caso agora, mas o [`Prepare()`](https://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php) também pode ser útil em outras situações.

Existem ainda outras formas de acessar isto, então é bom dar uma olhada na [documentação da classe](https://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3.php) como um todo, dá para aprender muito coisa legal lá, principalmente com os exemplos.

Outra [referência do mesmo manual](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlite.php) com informações mais completas e outras formas de recuperar os dados necessários usando uma classe um pouco diferente da que você está usando. Dê uma boa olhada, pode ser mais vantajoso trocar seu código para usar esta classe.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso mesmo, Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Tente do seguinte modo:

```
$select = "select count(*) as numeroOnline from users;";
$r = $base_hndl->exec($select);
$value = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
Echo "número online ".$value['numeroOnline'];
```

Sempre dava 1 porque você estava recebendo true ou false da função exec. Isso se você estiver suando PDO.

Comment: Uma observação, na primeira linha se vê que ele está usando a classe nativa, e não PDO.

Comment: Bem observado, eu tava no meu Tablet e nem percebi. Nunca fiz uso da classe nativa SQLite3, mas utilizo em muito a Classe PDO em meus projeto e recomendo, até mesmo com uso de sqlite, tanto pelo desempenho como segurança. Não posso falar nada da classe nativa, mas se houver alguém que a conheça pode dar sua opinião. OBS: Como Usar pdo com sqlite: $c = new PDO("sqlite:novo.sqlite");

Comment: Sem entrar em detalhes, as classes nativas são mais eficientes e seguras que o PDO, (no melhor caso empata na segurança). O PDO é uma camada de compatibilidade, e internamente usa a mesma API nativa de cada um dos DBs da mesma forma que as classes nativas, mas com mais código em cima pra simular um comportamento igual em todos os DBs, o que aumenta a área de exposição a problemas. A "vantagem" alegada do PDO é que uma vez que você aprenda a usar, faz igual pra todos os DBs (e perde o que cada um tem de melhor, em troca de um código "reusável", o que no fim é uma falácia).